# Arrays occupy the same memory? - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is from a javascript interface in Minecraft.
I can't find any documentation on why this is happening. I understand that if I change the ylist BEFORE zeroing it, it unlinks from xlist. (which is what I want) But why?

```js
// example 1
 xList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 xList.length = 0;
 yList = ["a", "b", "c"];
 xList = yList;
 yList.length = 0;
 // output is 
 // xlist.lenght = 0
 // xlist = []


// example 2
 xList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 xList.length = 0;
 yList = ["a", "b", "c"];
 xList = yList;
 yList = ["a", "xx", "c"];
 yList.length = 0;
 // output is 
 // xlist.lenght = 3
 // xlist = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: In your second example you allocate a new list `["a", "xx", "c"]` and point the variable `yList` to it. After this point `xList` still points to the original list. They no longer point to the same memory.

Comment: Yes but why when I zero it in the first example it isn't creating a new list?

Comment: Zeroing it does not create a new list — it changes the existing list. You create a new list when you type ` ["a", "b", "c"]`. in the first example you do this twice, in the second you do it three times. In the second example `xList = yList` means both variable point at the same list. But after you do `yList = ["a", "xx", "c"];` they longer do. `xList` still points to the original list so changing the new list has no effect on `xList` because you didn't change the list it is still pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code step by step

### Example 1:

1. `xList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`

```
xList -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

2. `xList.length = 0;`

```
xList -> []
```

3. yList = ["a", "b", "c"];

```
xList -> []
yList -> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

4. `xList = yList;`

```
xList -> yList = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

5. `yList.length = 0;`

```
xList -> yList -> []
```

### Example 2:

1. `xList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`

```
xList -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

2. `xList.length = 0;`

```
xList -> []
```

3. `yList = ["a", "b", "c"];`

```
xList -> []
yList -> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

4. `xList = yList;`

```
xList -> yList -> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

5. `yList = ["a", "xx", "c"];`

```
xList -> ["a", "b", "c"]
yList -> ["a", "xx", "c"]
```

6. `yList.length = 0;`

```
xList -> ["a", "b", "c"]
yList -> []
```

### Conclusion

Notice that `variable =` operator changes the variable while `variable.length` changes the value that the variable is pointing to

Comment: Just curious: Were you assisted by GPT for this answer?

Comment: @jsejcksn I wish I thought about that before I started writing that :D